# List validation(data annotation) not working on the client side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have a Groups list which has a custom attribute method associated with it. It does not seem to catch the validation error on the screen. However on the controller, it gives ModelState.Valid as false. Is there a way to catch it in the view instead of it having to go to the server side and I then catch and display it?
Other validations are working, so its not the case of missing jquery files.

Model:

```
   [RequiredList(ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Selected Organization(s)")]
    public List<OrganizationDTO> Organizations { get; set; }
```

Custom Attribute:

```
public class RequiredListAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var list = value as IList;
        if (list != null)
        {
            return list.Count > 0;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="controls">
          <label class="control-label" for="Selected Groups">Selected Group(s)</label>
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                     <div class="panel-body"  style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 100px; min-height:50px" id="divSelGroups">
                          @for (int i = 0; Model.Groups!= null && i < Model.Groups.Count(); i++)
                          {
                             var group= Model.Groups[i];
                             var checkedAttr = (group.Id != Guid.Empty) ? "checked='checked'" : "";
                              <div class="row">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="Groups.Index" value="@i" />
                                        <input type="hidden"name="Groups[@i].Name" value="@group.Name" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="Groups[@i].Data" value="@group.Data" />
                                        <div class="col-xs-1">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Groups[@i].Id" value="@group.Id" @checkedAttr data-org-selected="true" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-11" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="@group.Data">@group.Name</div>
                                </div>
                           }
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Groups)
          </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: A validation attribute needs to implement `IClientValidatable` and you need to write jquery methods for client side validation. But you cannot do that with a collection because you cannot create a form control for a collection (only properties of the objects in the collection)

Comment: @StephenMuecke But I am getting the error in ModelState.Valid. So is there a way I can catch it in the view itself instead of having to wait for the Submit?

Comment: Short answer is no (using a validation attribute). But you can write you own script (handle the forms submit event and check the data, and if not valid, cancel the submit and display and error message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to include a workaround to get it working, though does not answer my original question still gets the requirement of the question resolved. I had to introduce a hidden textbox which contains the number of list items and put a range validator on it.

Model:

```
[Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Atleast one organization needs to be selected.")]
public int OrgCount { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrgCount, new { style="visibility:hidden;height:0"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OrgCount)
```

JS script:

```
var orgCount = $(".panel-body  input[name='Organizations.Index']").last().val();
if (isNaN(orgCount))
    orgCount = -1;
$("#OrgCount").val(parseInt(orgCount) + 1);
```

So basically if there are no elements I make it 0 and hence they fail the validation and so the range validator error message is displayed.

Answer (score -2):

As per above information when the validation is working fine in the controller but it is not working  in the view then problem may regarding the jquery validation files .

So in your view if you havent reference the jquery files , then reference it like below:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Also make sure you have below entry in your webconfig file:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Hope above information will be useful , kindly let me your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

karthik